# Delegate router actions to to controllers in other apps

Tags: routes, elixir, phoenix-framework

I have an phoenix umbrella project with a number of routes related to my `main` app, then a number of routes related to my `child` app.

Currently I am binding to two ports (the ports which `main_web` and `child_web` are configured for) I then link to routes inside my `child` app referencing the url which my child port is associated with.

Could I instead bind to just one port and have something down the lines of the following `router.ex` files:

main_web/router.ex

```
scope "/" do
  pipe_through :browser

  get "/", MainWeb.PageController, :index
  resources "/user", MainWeb.UserController

  # Somehow delegating this to the ChildWeb app would be better
  scope "/child", ChildWeb do

    get "/", Page.Controller, :index
    resources "/other", OtherController
  end
end
```

child_web/router.ex

```
# if this is configured it would be everything after the /child url
scope "/", ChildWeb do
  get "/page1", Page1Controller, :index
end
```

I'm not sure entirely how this would be written, but I feel that the implementation for this may exist somewhere, if someone could reference to me an example or phoenix documentation for the above that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to use [`forward/4`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Router.html#forward/4):

```
forward "/child", ChildWeb.Router
```